# How to check if a letter is upper/lower cased?- Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The question is pretty self-explainable. I want to check if certain letter is uppercase or another letter is lowercase. Could you give me any examples of how to do that in **Flutter/Dart**?

Comment: you can use regular expressions!

Answer (score 5):

you can use the .toUpperCase() in a boolean statement:

```
bool isUppercased(String str){
  return str == str.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use regular expressions, here is how you could do:

```dart
bool isUpperCase(String letter) {
  assert(s.length == 1);
  final regExp = RegExp('[A-Z]');
  return regExp.hasMatch(letter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The one solution that is coming to my mind is to check its ASCII code.
The ASCII code of a-z starts at 97 and ends at 122.
Similarly, in the case of Uppercase letters A-Z it starts from 65 and ends at 90.

Keeping this in mind you can use the method `string.codeUnitAt(index)` which will return you the ASCII code and later you can check its range and find its an Uppercase or lowercase.

Have a look into this example

```
main() {

 String ch = 'Rose';
 print(' ASCII value of ${ch[0]} is ${ch.codeUnitAt(0)}');
   print(' ASCII value of ${ch[1]} is ${ch.codeUnitAt(1)}');

}
```

The output will be:

```
 ASCII value of R is 82

 ASCII value of o is 111
```

Now you can compare with the range using `if` statement and find out.